# How to divide total number of rows through matching rows in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a df with 100 rows. 25 of these rows match a specific criteria. I want to divide the total number of my df through my matching rows and add the value to a vector.

e.g. 100/25 = 25      ===> c(25)

Comment: Can you improve your example?

Comment: Is your example supposed to be `100/25 = 4 ===> c(4)`?

Answer (score 0):

`x<-1:100`

Criteria: 
<=25

`avector<-length(x)/sum(x<=25)`

If you need to append to an existing vector use `append`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution

```
df <- c(nrow(subset(data, var1 > 999))/(nrow(data)))
```